# Which subvarieties of $P^3$ are isomorphic to $P^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

What are all the subvarieties $X$ in the projective space $P^3$ such that $X$ is isomorphic to $P^2$?

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "subspace"?

Comment: "Any hypersurface of $P^3$ is isomorphic to $P^2$".
What???

Comment: The question becomes perfectly clear, non-trivial and legitimate just by changing "subspaces $X$" to "subvarieties $X$", as Nicolas Hemelsoet's answer confirms. I'm voting to reopen, after making the suggested modification.

Comment: It is extremely unfortunate that this question was closed. Many interesting answers could have been given in terms of: self intersection of canonical divisor, or arithmetic genus, or Euler characteristic, or signature of the underlying oriented smooth manifold, or... These answers would have had great pedagogical value to students of algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to know which hypersurface $X \subset \Bbb P^3$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb P^2$. First, it is clear that any linear equation $f(x,y,z,w) = 0$ defines such an hypersurface. Conversely, for $d \geq 2$ a surface of degree $d$ is not even diffeomorphic to $\Bbb P^2$ as an easy Euler characteristic computation shows, so any hypersurface isomorphic to $\Bbb P^2$ should be given by a linear equation.

Comment: Could you please explain your "easy" Euler characteristic computation ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : you are right, I should have not written "easy" : first one needs to show that all smooth hypersurfaces of fixed degree are diffeomorphic using Ehresmann's lemma. Then, it is enough to compute the Euler characteristic of $x_0^d + \dots + x_n^d = 0$ which can be done by induction, noticing that the projection onto $(x_0, \dots, x_{n-1})$ is a branched covering of $\Bbb P^{n-1}$, branched precisely at $x_0^d + \dots + x_{n-1}^d = 0$. When $n=3$, one needs to compute the Euler characteristic of a curve which is simply the genus-degree formula.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : Dear Georges, thanks also for your comment ! I should have also said that alternatively one could use the Euler sequence and Chern classes.

Comment: Dear Nicolas: I'm happy  that you could answer before the question was closed by five people whose contribution to algebraic geometry on this site varies from minimal to non-existent.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : I have to admit that I don't understand why such a question was closed. This system is pretty unfortunate ...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : I found another question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354053/rigid-and-nef-implies-numerically-trivial/2354085) where such thing happens as well (I had to do a bit of research but hopefully I could find it). As you said, a question is useful for the OP, but also for all the students in algebraic geometry who wants to learn new things. Maybe it should be possible to ask a moderator ?

Comment: Yes, it is very unfortunate that five people with zero qualification on a given subject (I do not refer specifically to the present case) can prevent tens of thousands of users  from  reading interesting answers by very knowledgeable experts.